# Angular 2 service get returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

In my current project, I have a very simple service which sets a string when a request comes from first page and show it in the second page using the same service. Setting the text is working perfectly. But when I called the get function, it returns undefined.

This is my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TsService {

  constructor() { }

  ts: string;

  getTs() : string {
      return this.ts;
  }

  setTs(ts) : void {
      this.ts = ts;
  }

}
```

In my first component I imported the Service

```
import { TsService } from './ts.service';
```

and added it to the providers

```
providers: [TsService]
```

and initialized in the contructor

```
private tsService: TsService
```

and to the button click, I set a string as well

```
this.tService.setTs(form.value.member)
```

In my second component, followed the same steps mentioned above except in the constructor I assigned as follows

```
this.ts = tsService.getTs();
```

but it gives me undefined. Is there anything that I missed

Comment: I'm guessing the form has no value when your constructor runs

Comment: It has a value, the form is the first page and it get a value from the form and when the button clicked, I set the value to the service and in the next component, I get the value

Comment: Can you include more of your code? Or make a plunkr? There might not be enough here to find the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can make out from your code. You have registered your service as a provider in your component. like

```
providers: [TsService]
```

What this line of code will do. Is that it will fetch a new Instance of your service as soon as your component comes into play. So from first component lets say `ComponentA` you set the service variable as

```
this.tService.setTs(form.value.member)
```

But here `ComponentA` is having suppose Instnace1 of the service. So you have set the value to Instance1 of the Service. Now you navigate to second component say `ComponentB` As soon as `ComponentB` comes into play it angular creates a new Instance of the service and  same is made available to `ComponentB`. Now there are two Instances of your service one with `ComponentA` and one with `ComponentB`. but you have set the variable using `ComponentA` so it wont be available to `ComponentB` hence

```
this.ts = this.tsService.getTs();
```

this returns undefined.

In order to check whether you variable is set or not you can try

```
this.tService.setTs(form.value.member);
console.log(this.tsService.getTs());
```

in your `ComponentA` it will log the value set.

The solution for this problem of your is to share the same Instance and that can be achieved by registering the service as provider in the `AppModule`.

As official docs say

> On the one hand, a provider in an NgModule is registered in the root
>   injector. That means that every provider registered within an NgModule
>   will be accessible in the entire application.

For more please refer :-

[Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html)

[NgModule Injectors](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-root-component-or-module)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks Manish for the suggestion, It worked and I missed it from the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the order in which stuff is executed it may well be that

```
this.tService.setTs(form.value.member)
```

is being executed **after**

```
this.ts = tsService.getTs();
```

In which case the behaviour is expected.

As for how to deal with this problem. One way is to add a way for components to subscribe to the service and get notified when **ts** changes so that they can react by executing some code. Look into [RxJS' Subject](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service).

A different reason may be that you are not providing the service correctly.

For example if you provide the service to a parent and a child component (direct or not). In that case the second provider may be shadowing the first due to Angular's [hierarchical dependency injection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html). Which means that one component is setting the value in one instance of the service and the other component is getting it from a different one. Unless you specifically need that kind of behaviour a service should only be provided at the root of the component tree where it's going to be used.

If your components are not related through the parent-child hierarchy then you should be providing the service only once. At the module level.

Without knowing more about your component structure it's not possible to tell what exactly is going on.

Comment: It looks like this might be the case, when I set a random text in the constructor it shows. I'll try with the RxJS

Comment: I've edited the answer with a link to Angular's documentation where they talk about component communication and in particular component communication through subscriptions using RxJS.

Comment: I was just thinking that there may be a different reason why this is happening, please check the edited answer.

Comment: They're 2 different components. The first component is the first page which has a form with a selection option using Radio button. Once the selection done, user clicks the button to the next page which is the second component. I have to show in the second component what he has selected in the first componet. They're not related as parent / child

Comment: Hi Rydion, Thanks for the suggestions and I fixed the issue. I followed Manish's suggestion about adding it to the app module

Answer (score 0):

You may have use two instances of data object.
use one data service for set and get data.Then you can access to same data object within different components.

And if you set that service as a provider for your components individually  those gonna work as different instances. If you need only one instance for your whole app you can set that service as a provider in **app.module.ts** file.